# Replacing spaces " " with \s using .replace()

Tags: python, regex

I have a set of two names with spaces in them. I want to do a regex search for "George Bush" or "Barack Obama". Following [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1371417?hl=en#Match-Word-or-Phrase-in-a-List) example I tried this, which gets the desired output

```
p = "(George\sBush|Barack\sObama)"
s = "recent Presidents George Bush and Barack Obama"
print re.findall(p,s) #Prints George Bush and Barack Obama
```

However, now I want to go from a list `["George Bush", "Barack Obama"]` to the pattern shown above.

I tried this:

```
for l in list:
     p = p + "|" + l
     p = p.strip("|")
p = ('.{75}(' + p + ').{75}').replace(" ", "\s")
```

But it gives : `'.{75}(George\\sBush|Barack\\sObama).{75}'`

How can I replace space characters with just "\s" instead of "\\s"?

Comment: The line with `s = recent` is invalid Python code, you are missing quotes around your string.

Answer (score 4):

You already have. The backslash is special and must be escaped in the representation (and *should* be escaped in the string), but you really *do* have "\s". Try printing the string instead.

Comment: If I print it, it still shows double slash. And that regex pattern does not work. What am I missing?